# INDEX+AGGREGATE Ignore duplicate results

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I would like to come up with a formula that compare two arrays. One of them has the ISO code for the the 50 states of the United States, the District of Columbia and Puerto Rico and in the second array just 20 of those territories. I would like to have the formula to ignore the duplicates between the two of them and just pull up the unique (or not duplicated) codes. So far I been able to do it with a very long and complicate formula. I was looking to find a way to simplify it.

```
=INDEX($B$4:$B$55,AGGREGATE(15,3,($B$4:$B$55<>$C$4)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$4)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$5)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$5)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$6)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$6)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$7)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$7)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$8)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$8)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$9)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$9)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$10)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$10)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$11)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$11)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$12)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$12)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$13)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$13)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$14)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$14)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$15)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$15)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$16)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$16)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$17)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$17)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$18)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$18)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$19)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$19)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$20)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$20)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$21)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$21)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$22)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$22)*($B$4:$B$55<>$C$23)/($B$4:$B$55<>$C$23)*(ROW($B$4:$B$55)-ROW($B$3)),ROWS($A$4:A4)),)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in `D4`:

```
{=INDIRECT(TEXT(MIN(IF(($B$4:$C$55<>"")*(COUNTIF($D$1:D3,$B$4:$C$55)=0),ROW($4:$55)*100+COLUMN($B:$C),7^8)),"R0C00"),)&""}
```

Entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Source: [Here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1966-excel-extract-unique-values-from-multiple-columns.html)